# How to locate yourself on a 2D colored grid?

Tags: probability, expected-value

### Problem

You are in a car on a finite 2D colour grid.
There are four colours; Red, Green, Blue and White.
You only know the colour of the current grid cell and the maximum of the past 10 colours.
The car moves randomly in four directions; up, down, left and right.
You have a map of this grid, but you don't know the orientation of the map.
How many steps does it take to locate yourself on this grid?

**Edit:** The colours are uniformly distributed and the possibility of encountering an edge can be ignored.

### My questions

1. I have to create a model of this problem. How should I go about it?
2. If I analyse, let's say 3 algorithms, I would compare the expected value of steps it takes to find my location. How would I calculate the expected value?

Comment: Any more information than that? Your description would apply to a grid with millions of squares, but with only one Green, Blue, and White square each well enough separated that you have forgotten the last such square before you encounter another, or an edge. In that case, you would never be able to completely locate yourself.

Comment: Hello Paul!
I edited my post to give more information.

Answer (score 0):

Consider your grid is $n.p$

You know a sequence of $k$ colours.
there are nearly $n.p$ starting places in the total grid, with $4$ directions for each of them.
Each one has a probability $1/4^k$ to match your pattern.
Numbers of solutions can be estimate with : $4 \times n \times p/4^k$

With $k = \frac{ln (4 \times n \times p)}{ln(4)}$, you can statically find the only solution in the grid.